# How can I know how many instances were made from a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance

I tried this program:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 10
        print(self.value)

t = Test()
t2 = Test()
```

I would like to know how many instances were made from the `Test` class.

Comment: Where would you like to track this? A file? In memory? Etc

Comment: I would track this in .py file

Comment: What? You aren't doing anything to track this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to create a counter for the class and increment them if a new instance is created, works in most cases.

However, you should keep some aspects in mind. What if a instance is removed? There is no mechanism to decrease this counter. To do this, you could use the [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method, which is called when the instance is about to be destroyed.

```
class Test:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Test.counter += 1
        self.id = Test.counter
    def __del__(self):
        Test.counter -= 1
```

But sometimes it can be problematic to find out, when an instance is deleted. In [this blog post](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/my-class-defines-del-but-it-is-not-called-when-i-delete-the-object.htm) you can find some more information if needed.

Comment: I find that this answer is more complete

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job, which you're looking for. Rest you can make a file and print the response. I am just representing the thing which you want for now:

```
class Test:
    # this is responsible for the count
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Test.counter += 1
        self.id = Test.counter

t = Test()
t2 = Test()
print(Test.counter)

# OUTPUT => 2
```